# XAMPP running Apache but not MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, webserver, xampp

So opening ports from router, turning off firewall and not having Skype I still can't get MySQL to stay running. It runs and then crashes straight away. The two logs can be found below. I had multiple xampp installs but deleted all but the original and turned the automatic processes off. What else can I do?

```
7:09:46 PM  [main]  Initializing Control Panel
7:09:46 PM  [main]  Windows Version: Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit
7:09:46 PM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 1.8.2
7:09:46 PM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
7:09:46 PM  [main]  Running with Administrator rights - good!
7:09:46 PM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\users\bfalcon\documents\xampp\"
7:09:46 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
7:09:50 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
7:09:50 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Initializing module...
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Checking for module existence...
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Checking for required tools...
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Checking for service (name="Apache2.4"): Service not     installed
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Service Path: Service Not Installed
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Checking default ports...
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Initializing module...
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Checking for module existence...
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Checking for required tools...
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Checking for service (name="mysql"): Service not installed
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Service Path: Service Not Installed
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Checking default ports...
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Initializing module...
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Checking for module existence...
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Checking for required tools...
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Checking for service (name="FileZillaServer"): Service not     installed
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Service Path: Service Not Installed
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Checking default ports...
7:09:50 PM  [mercury]   Initializing module...
7:09:50 PM  [mercury]   Checking for module existence...
7:09:50 PM  [mercury]   Checking for required tools...
7:09:50 PM  [mercury]   Checking default ports...
7:09:50 PM  [Tomcat]    Initializing module...
7:09:50 PM  [Tomcat]    Checking for module existence...
7:09:51 PM  [Tomcat]    Checking for required tools...
7:09:51 PM  [Tomcat]    Checking for service (name="Tomcat7"): Service not installed
7:09:51 PM  [Tomcat]    Service Path: Service Not Installed
7:09:51 PM  [Tomcat]    Checking default ports...
7:09:51 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
7:09:51 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
7:09:54 PM  [Apache]    Checking default ports...
7:09:54 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
7:09:54 PM  [Apache]    Executing "c:\users\bfalcon\documents\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"
7:09:54 PM  [Apache]    Return code: 0
7:09:55 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
7:10:03 PM  [mysql]     Checking default ports...
7:10:03 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
7:10:03 PM  [mysql]     Executing     ""c:\users\bfalcon\documents\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-    file="c:\users\bfalcon\documents\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini" --standalone"
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     Return code: 0
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
7:10:11 PM  [main]  Executing notepad.exe    c:\users\bfalcon\documents\xampp\mysql\data\mysql_error.log

7:09:46 PM  [main]  Initializing Control Panel
7:09:46 PM  [main]  Windows Version: Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit
7:09:46 PM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 1.8.2
7:09:46 PM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
7:09:46 PM  [main]  Running with Administrator rights - good!
7:09:46 PM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\users\bfalcon\documents\xampp\"
7:09:46 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
7:09:50 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
7:09:50 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Initializing module...
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Checking for module existence...
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Checking for required tools...
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Checking for service (name="Apache2.4"): Service not installed
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Service Path: Service Not Installed
7:09:50 PM  [Apache]    Checking default ports...
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Initializing module...
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Checking for module existence...
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Checking for required tools...
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Checking for service (name="mysql"): Service not installed
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Service Path: Service Not Installed
7:09:50 PM  [mysql]     Checking default ports...
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Initializing module...
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Checking for module existence...
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Checking for required tools...
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Checking for service (name="FileZillaServer"): Service not installed
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Service Path: Service Not Installed
7:09:50 PM  [filezilla]     Checking default ports...
7:09:50 PM  [mercury]   Initializing module...
7:09:50 PM  [mercury]   Checking for module existence...
7:09:50 PM  [mercury]   Checking for required tools...
7:09:50 PM  [mercury]   Checking default ports...
7:09:50 PM  [Tomcat]    Initializing module...
7:09:50 PM  [Tomcat]    Checking for module existence...
7:09:51 PM  [Tomcat]    Checking for required tools...
7:09:51 PM  [Tomcat]    Checking for service (name="Tomcat7"): Service not installed
7:09:51 PM  [Tomcat]    Service Path: Service Not Installed
7:09:51 PM  [Tomcat]    Checking default ports...
7:09:51 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
7:09:51 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
7:09:54 PM  [Apache]    Checking default ports...
7:09:54 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
7:09:54 PM  [Apache]    Executing "c:\users\bfalcon\documents\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"
7:09:54 PM  [Apache]    Return code: 0
7:09:55 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
7:10:03 PM  [mysql]     Checking default ports...
7:10:03 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
7:10:03 PM  [mysql]     Executing     ""c:\users\bfalcon\documents\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-   file="c:\users\bfalcon\documents\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini" --standalone"
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     Return code: 0
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another     method.
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
7:10:04 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
7:10:11 PM  [main]  Executing notepad.exe c:\users\bfalcon\documents\xampp\mysql\data\mysql_error.log
```

Comment: Have you checked for any rogue processes, that might be blocking the MySQL port? You could try to switch the port MySQL uses.

Comment: This could've happened after changing the root password and not changing it in the configuration file. Try resetting the root password.

Comment: no solution but: my experience is that it is much better to run a linux vm on a windows host instead of xampp. Easy to use and to port to another pc and you dont need to deal with windows issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
7:09:50 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules 
7:09:50 PM  [Apache] Initializing module... 
7:09:50 PM  [Apache] Checking for module existence... 
7:09:50 PM  [Apache] Checking for required tools... 
7:09:50 PM  [Apache] Checking for service (name="Apache2.4"): Service not installed<<<--    7:09:50 PM  [Apache] Service Path: Service Not Installed 
7:09:50 PM  [Apache] Checking default ports...
```

I would suggest you do deinstall every single rest of Xampp and reinstall it afterwards. It seems like you killed all your modules, but I am not sure thoug

Comment: Thanks so much! I'd tried that so many times before but I deleted all other xampps and re-installed it where the first instance was located.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the xampp mysql using "mysql_start" batch file which is under XAMPP folder.

Answer (score 0):

your installation failed:

```
Service Path: Service Not Installed
```

reinstall everything using the guide for your windows :

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#522

Comment: Thanks so much! I'd tried that so many times before but I deleted all other xampps and re-installed it where the first instance was located.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem for me:

1. Navigate to \xampp\mysql
2. Execute: mysql_uninstallservice.bat
3. Execute: mysql_installservice.bat
4. *Optionally reset root by executing: resetroot.bat*
5. Start XAMPP and you should see MySQL running.

Hope it works for you guys!